# Direct charges for standard account using strip/react-stripe-js stripe/stripe-js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create direct charges for my standard account using stripe.while doing this

- I'm not able setup application fee.

I'm creating 2 level of accounts  first main account or payment account,  under  payment account i'm creating connected account  and final customer for connected account.

My question is which accounts keys should be used to create customer is that payment account or connected account.  because its giving me error while using checkout like customer not exists.

<>

MY CODE
<>
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
name: name,
email: email,
phone: phone,
});[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ewY5.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXn0c.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3vol.png)
<>
const stripe_data = {
amount: intAmount,
currency: currency.toLowerCase(),
customer: customer.id,
setup_future_usage: "off_session",
metadata: description,
description: title,
automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true},
application_fee_amount: application_fee_amount,

```
   /* 
     Since We are charging customer directly below params  is not requird
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    on_behalf_of: bank_info.stripe_account_id,
    transfer_data: {
      destination: bank_info.stripe_account_id,
    },
    */
  };
  let paymentIntent = "";
  try {
    paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(stripe_data,{stripeAccount:  bank_info.stripe_account_id });
  } catch (e) {
     console.log("In Here")
     console.log(e)
    return res.status(500).json({
      status: "error",
      body: "Error in created payment order: " + e.code,
    });
  }
  console.log("PAYMENT==>",paymentIntent)
  const clientSecret = paymentIntent.client_secret;
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to to charge a connected account directly, you need to be using the connected account's keys.

To correctly set up application fees and direct charges, you can follow the guide provided in the Stripe documentation: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges

When creating a customer for the connected account, you can use the platform account's secret key. Here's an example of how to create a customer and charge them within the context of the connected account:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('{{YOUR_PLATFORM_SECRET_KEY}}');

// Create a customer for the connected account.
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  name: name,
  email: email,
  phone: phone,
}, {
  stripeAccount: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
});

// Create a direct charge with application fee for the connected account.
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
  amount: intAmount,
  currency: currency.toLowerCase(),
  customer: customer.id,
  automatic_payment_methods: {enabled: true},
  application_fee_amount: application_fee_amount,
}, {
  stripeAccount: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}',
});
```

Remember to replace **{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}** with the actual ID of the connected account.

By specifying the stripeAccount option, you're telling Stripe to perform the operation within the context of the connected account. This should resolve the "customer not exists" error you are encountering.

Comment: Yes have tried this but after  im getting error from frontend 

v3:1 Uncaught IntegrationError: Invalid value for elements(): clientSecret should be a client secret of the form ${id}_secret_${secret}. You specified: .
    at ne (v3:1:86615)
    at re (v3:1:86687)
    at new t (v3:1:298612)
    at e.<anonymous> (v3:1:372265)
    at e.<anonymous> (v3:1:92125)
    at e.o (v3:1:406644)
    at react-stripe.umd.js:385:1
    at basicStateReducer (react-dom.development.js:15195:1)
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:15318:1)

Comment: You are using/passing a wrong PaymentIntent Secret. You should pass PaymentIntent's clientSecret:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-client_secret

Comment: No the client secret which got as response  while creating paymentIntent only i'm using then also i got "The client_secret provided does not match any associated PaymentIntent on this account" as error, i know im missing something  with passing keys